# Почему не получается делать переадрессацию на файл index.php?

Tags: php

Есть вот такой код:

```
<?php
    include_once("settings.php");

    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $id_post = $_GET['id'];

    mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO comments(id_comment, id_post, 
    comment_text) VALUES ('', '$id_post', '$comment')");

    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
?>
```

И мне нужно сделать переадрессацию на файл index.php, который находится в той же папке, что и скрипт, но почему-то не получается туда попасть, и выдает ошибку:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
(output started at C:\OSPanel\domains\SomeTests\settings.php:7) in
C:\OSPanel\domains\SomeTests\DBcomments.php on line 9

Что делать?

Comment: Файл settings.php посмотреть бы. Посмотрите код файла settings на 7 строке что там

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего в файле `settings.php` вы выводите уже какой то контент, а в этом случае уже установить заголовки нельзя, сначала формируются заголовки и только потом тело ответа, вам нужно просто ничего не выводить на страницу до того момента пока все заголовки не проставите, но чаще всего просто используют буффер и не переживают за заголовки:

```
<?php
ob_start();
// code here
ob_end_flush();
```

Или же в `php.ini` установить значение для `output_buffering`, это самые простые варианты, а вообще есть много вариантов решения.

Comment: Спасибо большое!